# Unity - кнопка под другой кнопкой не нажимается

Tags: unity3d, ui

есть 2 кнопки, start и air. air находится выше кнопки start. При этом компонент Button у air удалён, то есть эта кнопка не кликабельна. Но при этом пользователь должен иметь возможность нажать на кнопку start, хоть air и перекрывает её. Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: Какой-то когнитивный диссонанс. нерабочая кнопка над рабочей. Надо сделать чтобы нерабочая стала выше.......Ну у вас всё сделано!

Comment: @АлексейШиманский подредактировал вопрос, теперь всё должно стать понятным.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос скрин окна редактора, а то сложновато представить в голове.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите с всех перекрывающих `Image` содержащих обьектов галочку `Raycast Target`, это даже может быть прозрачный фон на всю область камеры мешать нажимать на кнопку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]